# AspnetSqlMembershipProvider: require minimum length for username

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke

I am using dotnetnuke 4.9.5 (ASP.Net 2.0) and its default membership provider i.e. AspnetSqlMembershipProvider. Currently a username of length 1 is legal. Is there anyway I could restrict the minimum length for username?

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel's method is probably way easier, but you could also implement a custom membership provider and inherit from the SqlMembershipProvider and add that validation in the CreateUser method.  You might want to refer to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/customaspnetproviders.aspx) (caution: it is VB not C#).

Don't be intimidated, though -- since you'll be inheriting most of the base class's logic, your only work will really be to add in your validation on that one method.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlMembershipProvider doesn't have configuration for anything about username length.  Why not just validate the text input manually?

Comment: This is the only thing that I myself could think of. I was just wondering if I missed something.